# UIControll in UIScrollView not receiving touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiswitch, uicontrol

I use [SevenSwitch](https://github.com/bvogelzang/SevenSwitch) in my project. I need to add it into a `UIScrollView` but it seems that the control can not receive touch events when I add it into scroll view.

I tried sub classing `scrollview` and overriding below code:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
  return NO;
}
```

also added:

```
self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

but still can not receive the touch event. How can I stop `scrollview` from preventing the `UIControl` from receiving touches?

**Update**

I have a tap gesture on my scroll view because I want that when user tap the scroll view I call `[self.scrollView endEditing:YES]` to close the keyboard. When I remove it the seven switch is working with tap.

I add below code to my tap gesture:

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

and now the `sevenswitch` is working with tap but there is problems when make the switch `on` or `off` with touch tracking.

Comment: anybody have any idea?

Comment: why you want to have touch event inside it? i have made sample demo of it with putting SevenSwitch inside scrollview and it's working properly(getting the action of control) without making any changes

Comment: I do not want to have touch event. I only wants that it works. When I add it to the scroll view I can not toggle it on

Answer (score 3):

I have made sample in which i have sevenswitch inside the scrollview and it's working properly

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SevenSwitch *mySwitch = [[SevenSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    mySwitch.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.5);
    [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //[self.view addSubview:mySwitch];

    mySwitch.on = true;

    [_cntView addSubview:mySwitch];

    SevenSwitch *mySwitch3 = [[SevenSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    mySwitch3.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.5 + 70);
    [mySwitch3 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:mySwitch3];

    //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.19f green:0.23f blue:0.33f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.thumbTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.19f green:0.23f blue:0.33f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.activeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.07f green:0.09f blue:0.11f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.inactiveColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.07f green:0.09f blue:0.11f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.onTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.45f green:0.58f blue:0.67f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mySwitch3.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [_cntView addSubview:mySwitch3];
}

- (void)switchChanged:(SevenSwitch *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Changed value to: %@", sender.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF");
}
```

In which `_cntView` is the main container view which i have placed inside the scrollview , please check if this working for you

---

**Update**

As i mention in the comment i didn't getting what you are trying to say with touch tracking but i have made sample with tap gesture in the scrollview which may help

```
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,700)];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];

    SevenSwitch *mySwitch = [[SevenSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    mySwitch.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.5);
    [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //[self.view addSubview:mySwitch];

    mySwitch.on = true;

    [scrollview addSubview:mySwitch];

    SevenSwitch *mySwitch3 = [[SevenSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    mySwitch3.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.5 + 70);
    [mySwitch3 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    mySwitch3.thumbTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.19f green:0.23f blue:0.33f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.activeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.07f green:0.09f blue:0.11f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.inactiveColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.07f green:0.09f blue:0.11f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.onTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.45f green:0.58f blue:0.67f alpha:1.00f];
    mySwitch3.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mySwitch3.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [scrollview addSubview:mySwitch3];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [scrollview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}


- (void)actionSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Tap");
}

- (void)switchChanged:(SevenSwitch *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Changed value to: %@", sender.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF");
}
```

I have made all the new code programatically and it detects touch events outside the sevenSwitch and also detect touch/tap on the seven switch also.
If you want to make it make scrollview in Storyboard and change the programatic scrollview with the storyboard outlet

Comment: I also create what you do in a new fresh create view controller that made in storyboard. Now sevenswitch works with tap but have problem with track touching.
Also I creating my scroll view programmatically and add it to the view. In this scrollview it is not working even by tapping.

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad so now does it works in your scrollview programatically? also ` touch tacking` means it don't work with pan/drag gesture on the switch ?

Comment: touch tracking do not work with storyboard and with my programmatically scrollview added

Comment: sorry i am not getting your issue of touch tracking

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad i have updated code, if you still have issue

Comment: Single tap is working. Do not required a new gesture. holding and tracking the sevenswitch is the problem . It has bad animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}

- (void)actionSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:self.scrollView];
    NSLog(@"Touch point coordinates are : %f - %f", touchPoint.x , touchPoint.y );

    UIView *hitImageView = [self.scrollView hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", hitImageView);

    switch (hitImageView.tag) {
        case 1:
            // do something
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Single tap is working. Do not required a new gesture. holding and tracking the sevenswitch is the problem . It has bad animation