# Xamarin.iOS:TouchEvent cannot been called in UIScrollView

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to add TouchEvent into a UIScrollView but it seems the method `TouchesBegan` will never been called when I touch the ScrollView.I find a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336648/uicontroll-in-uiscrollview-not-receiving-touch-events).And I have to add a singleTapGesture .However,I can't do that for some reason.Is it the only solution？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize a subclass that inherits from `UIScrollView`.And override the  method `TouchesBegan` `TouchesBegan` and `TouchesMoved`

```
public class MyScrollerView: UIScrollView
{
    public MyScrollerView()
    {

    }
    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.NextResponder.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
    }

    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.NextResponder.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.NextResponder.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);
    }

}
```

> in xxx.cs

```
var myScrollView = new MyScrollerView();
myScrollView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
myScrollView.DelaysContentTouches = false; // it is important
//. . .
```

And now you can call the method `TouchesBegan` `TouchesBegan` and `TouchesMoved` in the `ViewController`

```
public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
     // do some you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a gesture recognizer on any view, doing this:

```
myView.AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(() =>
{
  //Do Something
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.As I said that I couldn't add a TapGesture